# IBM Watson Studio Installation Problem Stuck at "Pre-install script timeout, trying again"

Tags: linux, data-science-experience, watson-studio

I am installing the Watson Studio 1.2.2 on a 5 nodes environment

However, the installation is stuck at the
"Testing the connection to root@node 1 '192.168.123.130' "
"Pre-install script timeout, trying again"

For your reference

- I install the Watson Studio at the 5 nodes environment ( 3 Control/Storage/Compute nodes + 2 Deployment Node )
- OS - RHEL 7.5
- All Servers are able to ping and SSH passwordless
- Reserved 1 unused virtual IP
- All the server already passed the pre_install_check.sh test

Could you guys please help to suggest the solution for this installation problem ?

Comment: FYI, 192.168.123.130 is the master node which run the installer.